# Grub problem after installation

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04

I wanted to install Ubuntu to my fujitsu desktop pc so I created a live usb , booted it and clicked on install. I didn't notice it was installing to my 500 gb portable HDD as it had the most free space.

It created a new partition and then finished the installation. After restarting, my pc says the (partition) cannot be found and so enters grub rescue.
Apparently Ubuntu created an entry in the Grub menu but it can't find the HDD on boot.

My PC and all files are intact but Windows isn't booting, and my BIOS is locked with a password so I cannot change BIOS settings.

PC Specs:

- 1.87 GB ram
- 3.6 GHz Pentium (dual core) processor
- PHOENIX BIOS
- 320 GB hitachi HDD
- 500 GB toshiba portable HDD

Comment: You can reset your BIOS settings, and thus the password, by removing the battery or pressing/switching the CMOS switch on your mainboard.

Answer (score 1):

The easy option is just to boot from the live usb, install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from the software center, then run it.